# devtools::test() fails with: unable to find an inherited method for function "my_function" for signature '"MyClass'"

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, devtools, r-s4

I have an S4 class:

```
#' @title
#'     my S4 class
#' @description
#'     my basic class
#' @slot field_1 a numerical field
@export
MyClass <- setClass(
    "MyClass",
    representation(
        field_1 = "numeric"
    ),
    prototype(
        field_1 = numeric()
    )
)

#' @title
#'     A function to set the field_1 value
#' @description
#'    Takes an input value and sets the field_1 value based off that input
#' @return object with field_1 value set
#' @export
setGeneric(
    "set_field_1",
    function(object, value) standardGeneric("set_field_1")
)
setMethod("set_field_1",
    signature = "MyClass",
    definition = function(object, value) {
        object@field_1 <- value
        return(object)

    }
)
```

I have a covering test:

```
test_that("test set_field_1 works properly", {
    my_class <- MyClass()
    returned_val <- set_field_1(my_class, 4)
})
```

When I run my test using:
`test_file("./tests/testthat/test_my_class.R")` my test passes fine.
When I run `devtools::test()` on all my tests, I get:

```
test_my_class.R:3: error: test set_field_1 works properly
unable to find an inherited method for function 'set_field_1' for signature '"MyClass"'
Backtrace:
1. mycodebase::set_field_1(my_class, 4)
```

What is going on?
I've tried

devtools::document()

devtools::check() # fails on tests

The code runs fine, it's just when using `devtools::test()` as far as I can tell. Something's not being updated, but I don't know how to troubleshoot what, or what to try next

Comment: does adding `@exportMethods` to the generic solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to R and not clear what a "generic" is with respect to classes, methods etc... Where should @exportMethods go - i.e. which file and in which position in that file?

Comment: put it just above `setGeneric` (that is the call that defines a generic function)

Answer (score 0):

So the issue seems to have been in the tests.
I an entirely separate piece of test code I had used the mockery "stub" method, with argument depth=2.
e.g.

```
stub(a_different_function, "flog.logger", mock(), depth=2)
```

depth=2 as a_different_function called another function and this allowed me to use a mock in that sub call too (this seems to be consistent with the mockery usage documentation).

However, that seems to have resulted in all class inheritance being knocked out, i.e. anywhere where an S4 class had inherited methods, those methods would through the equivalent of the above error.

For now I've reverted to using the older:
with_mock({...}) method for mocking cases where depth needs to be >1